# Not able to forward declare a class which is inside a namespace

Tags: c++, c++14, visual-studio-2022

I have following files

refiner.h

```
#include "schemes.h"

namespace MyLib {
    namespace MyLibVersion {
        namespace Far {
            class Refiner {
            public:
                Sdc::SchemeType const GetScheme() { return _scheme; }
            private:
                Sdc::SchemeType _scheme;
            };
        }
    }
    using namespace MyLibVersion;
}
```

schemes.h

```
namespace MyLib {
    namespace MyLibVersion {
        namespace Sdc {
            enum SchemeType {
                SCHEME_1,
                SCHEME_2,
                SCHEME_3
            };
        }
    }
    using namespace MyLibVersion;
}
```

utils.h

```
namespace MyLib {
    namespace Far {
        class Refiner;
    }
}

class Utils
{
    MyLib::Far::Refiner* createRefiner();
};
```

utils.cpp

```
#include "utils.h"
#include "refiner.h"

using namespace MyLib;

Far::Refiner* Utils::createRefiner()
{
    Far::Refiner* refiner = new Far::Refiner();
    refiner->GetScheme();
}
```

I get error in the file utils.cpp that "Error C2872 'Far': ambiguous symbol". I was thinking that in utils.h I have forward declared the class 'Refiner' and I am including the header refiner.h in utils.cpp where it is defined. So why is it ambiguous?

Comment: Are there no notes explaining the error further?

Comment: Your `Refiner` is in `MyLib::MyLibVersion::Far`, so don't forward-declare it in  `MyLib::Far`.

Comment: But I have the statement "using namespace MyLibVersion;" in every header file right after the MyLibVersion namespace, so, it is basically making that namespace available there only. Is that not so?

Comment: That is so. But it doesn't magically move `class Refiner;` forward declaration to `MyLibVersion` namespace. It still forward-declares a class named `Refiner` in namespace named `MyLib::Far`. So now your program has two distinct classes, both named `Refiner` - one in namespace `MyLib::Far` (only declared, not implemented) and one in namespace `MyLib::MyLibVersion::Far` In fact, you now have two namespaces named `Far` - one in `MyLib` and another in `MyLib::MyLibVersion`. In `Far::Refiner`, the compiler can't even figure out which `Far` you mean, let alone which `Refiner`